# How to convert a wide voltage range (1 V-12 V) to 5 V?

Tags: voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, boost, ldo, buck-boost

I have an unusual application where the input voltage can vary from 1-12 V DC. This must be converted to 5 V @ ~200-250 mA.

Since there are no available buck-boost converters suitable for this wide input voltage range, I came up with this (simplified) circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhnUa5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The XC61CC5002MR-G is a voltage CMOS supervisory IC which:

- Outputs VCC when VCC > 5 V - this enables the LDO and protects the
  boost converter from the higher voltage.
- Outputs 0 V when V<sub>CC</sub> < 5 V - this disables the LDO and biases the PMOS transistor to allow current to the boost converter.

The boost converter's absolute maximum voltage rating is 6 V, so it needs to be protected at the higher range of input voltage, whilst the LDO is OK up to 13 V.

The circuit worked as intended from 3-12 V, however the PMOS transistor couldn't switch when the input voltage was lower than 3 V, which shouldn't have surprised me since the V<sub>GS</sub> threshold was about 2 V at 250 mA.

I have also looked at high-side load switches and over-voltage protection ICs, but I cannot find any that will operate over the whole range of the input voltages after browsing for hours on Mouser and DigiKey.

Lastly I have explored using a N-channel MOSFET in the circuit above with an open-drain output variant of the same supervisory IC and a charge pump to bias the NMOS transistor when voltages are low, but to my surprise I couldn't find any charge pumps that work in the 1-5 V range.

I am looking for any suggestions to either make my circuit work with the lower voltages or how else I can achieve this 1-12 V to 5 V conversion without dramatically increasing the PCB footprint or cost. Unfortunately the input voltage cannot be changed, but the power supply can provide more than enough current to run the circuit.

Comment: Welcome to the site.

Comment: What part is the boost converter?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61099.pdf

Comment: Have you had a look at doing your own buck-boost converter? The control loop is a bit tricky, but it would be the "proper" way to do what you're attempting.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't be possible since this is not a one off project

Comment: Basic physics says that at 5V and 250mA out, a 1V input would have to supply at least 7.5A.  Probably more like 9A with realistic efficiency assumptions (assumption -- efficiency is poor down there).  Will your source supply that when it's riding at 1V?

Comment: @TimWescott How did you obtain 7.5A?

Comment: @TimWescott surely it would be 1.25A + head room for inefficiency?

Comment: @jm212121 it's 1.25A + inefficiency + **forgetting that I should not do math in my head**.  Dangit.  Yes -- 1.25A + inefficiency.  Probably 1.5A more or less, depending on how efficient the conversion ends up being.

Comment: @jm212121 -- do you have to be able to *start up* on a 1V supply, or can you guarantee a higher voltage at startup?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes I have to be able to start up at 1V

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to make this circuit suggestion:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEz1ex.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For 1 V < Vin < 6 V the boost converter converts to a 6 V internal voltage and the LDO regulates that 6 V down to 5 V

For 6 V < Vin < 12 V the voltage at the Boost converter's output will "follow" the input voltage with some voltage drop due to a (Schottky) diode, so Vin = 7 V => Vmid = 6.5 V and Vin = 12 V => Vmid = 11.5 V.

Remember that boost converters have this basic circuit:

[image]

So when Vin is higher than the configured (regulated) output voltage, the output will follow the input voltage with a voltage drop from the coil's resistance and the diode.

Comment: Are you aware of a boost converter that works down to 1 volt and can live with voltages at the input as high as 12 volts? Or are you suggesting "build from scratch"?

Comment: @Andyaka No, I'm not. I just provide the circuit idea :-) Closest I know: CE8301 it can work from 0.9 V up to 10 V.

Comment: The boost converter I am using can only tolerate up to 6v according to its absolute maximum ratings and I have looked around and don't think there are any that can tolerate any more than 6v whilst boosting from 1v.

Comment: LT1615 seems to be a good match for the boost part. Starts up from 1V, doesn't burn up to 15V.

Comment: Just had a look at the LT1615 and it cannot produce enough current at the lower voltages.

Comment: At 250mA out, with 12V in, your linear regulator would be burning off a bit over 10W -- that's a lot.

Comment: @jm212121 Mmh, that's right. But I had a look at the TPS61099, and it can't do it either. Worst case switch current limit is 0.8A. At 1V input, you need 5*250mA, not even accounting for the ripple. It's going to be hard.

Comment: You are right, my current requirements were slightly overestimated, but I have tested the TPS61099 and can get up to 120mA out from it from 1V input, which would probably suffice.

Comment: I am happy with the TPS61099 as the boost converter since it is less likely to be at 1V and its a case of I'll take what current I can get (ie the 250mA is not imperative but preferable), but what I am having difficulty with is the rest of the circuit.

Comment: @TimWescott I don't understand your 10 W, according to me it is less than: 12 V - 5 V = 7 V => x 250 mA = 1.75 W for the dissipation in the LDO.

Comment: *but what I am having difficulty with is the rest of the circuit.* Which circuit do you mean? If you would use the TPS61099 then there is no "rest of the circuit" needed because this IC can behave as an LDO when Vin > Vout. Do note that the TPS61099 is limited to a 5.5 V maximum input voltage.

Comment: How can the IC behave as an LDO for the voltages over 5V up to 12V when it's maximum input voltage is 5.5V? It says in the data sheet any voltages above 5.5 may cause damage.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Oh damn.  I was doing math in my head again.  This happens just often enough that I should know better, and yet I always get sucked in.  For what little it's worth, if it's a paying job I double-check!  2W is still enough that you need to think about getting the heat out of the part, of course, but it's not THAT bad.

Answer (score 2):

### A SEPIC might be worth a shot here

This situation (wide voltage range input, fixed voltage output, low-ish current requirements) strikes me as a decent opportunity to try one of the lesser-used switching topologies: the SEPIC.  In particular, I would use a [LM2621](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2621.pdf) converter IC with a low-drop Schottky diode -- this gives the chip the best chance of starting up at or about 1.0V (the datasheet specifies nominal startup at 1.1V and maximum startup at 1.2V over temperature, but the startup voltage likely depends on the drop across the diode).

As to passives, I would use the [coupled-inductor version](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt309/slyt309.pdf) of the SEPIC topology -- this gives better ripple performance while using less board space than two separate inductor cores.

Comment: Funnily enough, I discovered the LM2621 yesterday and I have ordered one, will post update if it works out.

Comment: Thank you for linking that SEPIC article it was very informative, I have a question with the coupled inductor SEPIC topology would the voltage at the diode be limited to 5V? Because if so I could use a MAX40200 ideal diode current switch: (https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX40200.pdf) which has a very small forward voltage but is only rated at maximum 6V.

Comment: @jm212121 the voltage across L1b is Vin+Vout, so you'll need a much higher voltage part than that -- switching speed would also be an issue for many/most "ideal diodes".  What you really need is a *synchronous rectification controller* if you want to do what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the EXTREME switch, you need a flyback stepup with zener post-regulator, to provide the FET's gate drive.

Set the zener at 10 or 12 volts. Many huge FETS want a low max gate voltage (from what I recall).

Now you can use a LARGE FET, capable of 10 or 20 amps or whatever you need, that FET gate being driven 0/10 volts for efficient switching.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS4xZS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean here - that diagram is confusing me. In the diagram you have a 1-12 volt boost regulator, is that a boost regulator that accepts 1-12 volts as input, if so I can't seem to find one that accepts that range while maintaining a few hundred milliAmps at 1v.

Comment: The bottom switcher ---- the flyback ----has to operate on 1 volt, or higher. Simply having a circuit that oscillates at 1 volt requires some thinking. Then you want that oscillator to operate a transistor in boost mode, with the output regulated by a 10 volt zener. The 10 volts is used in the very-high-current upper switcher, perhaps solely to drive the gate of the 20Amp? MOSFET. By having 10 volts to control the gate, instead of 1 volt, you make much more efficient use of the big MOSFET.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to skin a cat, and this is a particularly vicious cat.  Here's my thoughts:

Boost set to 5.5V or so.  I'd have to go shopping for parts to be sure, but I suspect you'll need something with an external switch to handle the 8-9A input at 1V.  Follow that with a buck to 5V, to handle the case when the input's above 5V.  Don't mess with the linear supplies unless you need really clean power.

If you can't find a suitable boost chip or switch FET, use a lightweight boost that's just big enough to power the "real" boost controller (and by extension, the "big" switch gate).  Maybe even switch the lightweight guy out of the circuit if the input voltage gets too high.